# AppEngine - trying to redirect to new page after OpenID login

Tags: python, google-app-engine, openid

I'm using Google App Engine (Python), and using OpenID for login.  Specifically, I'm playing with the GitHub project from "metachris" here: https://github.com/metachris/appengine-boilerplate

I believe the relevant section of code (App Handler for Login) is here:

```
class LogIn(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        action = decode(self.request.get('action'))
        target_url = decode(self.request.get('continue'))
        if action and action == "verify":
            f = decode(self.request.get('openid_identifier'))
            url = users.create_login_url(target_url, federated_identity=f)
            self.redirect(url)
        else:
            self.response.out.write(template.render(tdir + "login.html", \
                {"continue_to": target_url}))
```

And the login.html code includes:

```
    <!-- Simple OpenID Selector --> 
    <form action="/login" method="get" id="openid_form"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="verify" /> 
        {% if continue_to %}<input type="hidden" name="continue" value="{{ continue_to }}" />{% endif %}        
        <fieldset> 
            <legend>Sign-in or Create New Account</legend> 
            <div id="openid_choice"> 
                <p>Please click your account provider:</p> 
                <div id="openid_btns"></div> 
            </div> 
            <div id="openid_input_area"> 
                <input id="openid_identifier" name="openid_identifier" type="text" value="http://" /> 
                <input id="openid_submit" type="submit" value="Sign-In"/> 
            </div> 
        </fieldset> 
    </form> 
    <!-- /Simple OpenID Selector -->
```

Right now, after logging in the app takes people back to the root page.  I'd like to take them to a new home page for logged in users.  I've tried varying a bunch of the parameters but I haven't gotten it to work.

Can anyone point me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say, are you setting the 'continue' query parameter on your login url? If not, try `/login?continue=/logged-in`.

First time around `target_url` is being set from the query parameter, it's then being fed into your form using `continue_to`. The result of it being in the form is that the query parameter will persist when you submit the form. Next time around, because `verify` is now set, `target_url` will be fed to `create_login_url()`. Assuming the openid code does the right thing, your openid provider should redirect the user back to `/logged-in`.

Comment: Thanks, Dan.  That's exactly what I needed, and it works!  What you mentioned around 'verify' being set and automatically going to 'logged-in' doesn't seem to be working, but that's something for a later date.  I needed to get the main screens hacked together first.